# Pong game using SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, game, c++11, sdl

I've just finished writing my first game: a clone of the classic Pong game for Linux and Mac only. You will need SDL 2.0, SDL_ttf 2.0 and SDL_Mixer 2.0 to compile it. The complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/chaficnajjar/pong).

My experience with C++ and game development in general is fairly limited and I would like to know what could be improved in my code.

Some questions I have:

1. Would it be better to use OOP?
2. Should I be using headers?
3. Should I divide the code into multiple files?

```
/*
 *  Pong game
 *  Author: Chafic Najjar <chafic.najjar@gmail.com>
 *  Note: Origin of the coordinate system is the upper left corner of the screen
 */

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>                   // SDL library
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>               // SDL font library
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>             // SDL sound library
#include <cmath>                        // abs()
#include <ctime>                        // rand()

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

SDL_Window*     window;                 // holds window properties
SDL_Renderer*   renderer;               // holds rendering surface properties

SDL_Texture*    font_image_score1;      // holds text indicating player 1 score (left)
SDL_Texture*    font_image_score2;      // holds text indicating palyer 2 score (right)
SDL_Texture*    font_image_winner;      // holds text indicating winner
SDL_Texture*    font_image_restart;     // holds text suggesting to restart the game
SDL_Texture*    font_image_launch1;     // holds first part of text suggesting to launch the ball
SDL_Texture*    font_image_launch2;     // holds second part of text suggesting to launch the ball

Mix_Chunk *paddle_sound;                // holds sound produced after ball collides with paddle
Mix_Chunk *wall_sound;                  // holds sound produced after ball collides with wall
Mix_Chunk *score_sound;                 // holds sound produced when updating score

SDL_Color dark_font = {67, 68, 69};     // dark grey
SDL_Color light_font = {187, 191, 194}; // light grey

bool done = false;                      // true when player exits game

// Screen resolution
int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

// Controllers
bool mouse = true;
bool keyboard = false;

// Mouse coordinates;
int mouse_x, mouse_y;

// Paddle lengths
const int PADDLE_WIDTH = 10;
const int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;

// Paddle position
int left_paddle_x = 40; 
int left_paddle_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 30;

int right_paddle_x = SCREEN_WIDTH - (40+PADDLE_WIDTH);
int right_paddle_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 30;

// Launch ball
bool launch_ball = false;

// Ball dimensions
const int BALL_WIDTH = 10;
const int BALL_HEIGHT = 10;

// Ball position
int x_ball = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int y_ball = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

// Ball movement
int ball_dx = 0;        // movement in pixels over the x-axis for the next frame (speed on the x-axis)
int ball_dy = 0;        // movement in pixels over the y-axis for the next frame (speed on the y-axis)

int speed = 8;          // ball speed = √(dx²+dy²)
int hit_count = 0;      // counts the number of hits of the ball with the right paddle
                        // after three hits, speed increases by one 

float angle = 0.0f;     // angle on collision with paddle

bool bounce = false;    // true when next frame renders ball after collision impact (ball has bounced)

// Match score
int score1 = 0;
int score2 = 0;

bool left_score_changed = true;     // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 
bool right_score_changed = true;    // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 

// Prediction
int final_predicted_y;              // predicted ball position on y-axis after right paddle collision (used for paddle AI)

// Font names
string fonts[] = {"Lato-Reg.TTF", "FFFFORWA.TTF"};

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, SDL_Rect dst, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, clip, &dst);
}

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr) {
    SDL_Rect dst;
    dst.x = x;
    dst.y = y;
    if (clip != nullptr){
        dst.w = clip->w;
        dst.h = clip->h;
    }

    else
        SDL_QueryTexture(tex, NULL, NULL, &dst.w, &dst.h);

    renderTexture(tex, ren, dst, clip);
}

SDL_Texture* renderText(const string &message, const string &fontFile, SDL_Color color, int fontSize, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);

    SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);

    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    return texture;
}

// Imprecise prediction of ball position on the y-axis after right paddle collision 
int predict() {

    // Find slope
    float slope = (float)(y_ball - y_ball+ball_dy)/(x_ball - x_ball+ball_dx);

    // Distance between paddles
    int paddle_distance = right_paddle_x - (left_paddle_x+PADDLE_WIDTH); 

    // Prediction without taking into consideration upper and bottom wall collisions
    int predicted_y = abs(slope * -(paddle_distance) + y_ball);

    // Calculate number of reflexions
    int number_of_reflexions = predicted_y / SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    // Predictions taking into consideration upper and bottom wall collisions
    if (number_of_reflexions % 2 == 0)                      // Even number of reflexions
        predicted_y = predicted_y % SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    else                                                    // Odd number of reflexsion
        predicted_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - (predicted_y % SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    return predicted_y;

}

// Get user input
void input() {

    SDL_Event event;    // stores next event to be processed

    // Queuing events
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        // Track mouse movement
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);

        // Clicking 'x' or pressing F4
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            done = true;

        // Pressing a key
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {

                // Pressing ESC exits from the game
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;

                // Pressing space will launch the ball if it isn't already launched
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    if (!launch_ball) {
                        int direction = 1+(-2)*(rand()%2);                  // either 1 or -1
                        angle = rand()%120-60;                              // between -60 and 59
                        ball_dx = direction*speed*cos(angle*M_PI/180.0f);   // speed on the x-axis
                        ball_dy = speed*sin(angle*M_PI/180.0f);             // speed on the y-axis

                        // Find slope
                        float slope = (float)(y_ball - y_ball+ball_dy)/(x_ball - x_ball+ball_dx);

                        // Distance between left paddle and center
                        int paddle_distance = SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - (left_paddle_x+PADDLE_WIDTH); 

                        // Predicting where the left paddle should go in case ball is launched left
                        final_predicted_y = abs(slope * -(paddle_distance) + y_ball);

                        launch_ball = true;
                    }
                    break;

                // Pressing F11 to toggle fullscreen
                case SDLK_F11:
                    int flags = SDL_GetWindowFlags(window);
                    if(flags & SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
                        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, 0);
                    else
                        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
                    break;
            }

    }
}

// Check if collision with left paddle occurs in next frame
bool checkLeftCollision() {
    if (!(x_ball + ball_dx <= left_paddle_x + PADDLE_WIDTH))
        return false;
    if (x_ball < left_paddle_x)
        return false;
    if (!(y_ball + BALL_WIDTH >= left_paddle_y && y_ball <= left_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT))
        return false;
    return true;
}

// Check if collision with right paddle occurs in next frame
bool checkRightCollision() {
    if (!(x_ball + BALL_WIDTH + ball_dx >= right_paddle_x))
        return false; 
    if (x_ball > right_paddle_x + PADDLE_WIDTH)
        return false;
    if (!(y_ball + BALL_WIDTH > right_paddle_y && y_ball <= right_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT))
        return false;
    return true;
}

// Update game values
void update() {

    // Right paddle follows the player's mouse movement on the y-axis
    if (mouse == true)
        right_paddle_y = mouse_y;

    /* Basic AI */
    // Ball on the left 3/5th side of the screen and going left
    if (x_ball < SCREEN_WIDTH*3/5 && ball_dx < 0) { 
        // Follow the ball
        if (left_paddle_y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT - BALL_HEIGHT)/2 < final_predicted_y-2)
            left_paddle_y += speed/8 * 5;
        else if (left_paddle_y + (PADDLE_HEIGHT - BALL_HEIGHT)/2 > final_predicted_y+2)
            left_paddle_y -= speed/8 * 5;
    }

    // Ball is anywhere on the screen but going right
    else if (ball_dx >= 0) {

        // Left paddle slowly moves to the center
        if (left_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2 < SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)
            left_paddle_y += 2;
        else if (left_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2 > SCREEN_HEIGHT/2) 
            left_paddle_y -= 2;
    }


    /* Paddle-wall collision */

    // No need to anticipate the right paddle going above the screen, mouse coordinates cannot be negative

    // Right paddle shouldn't be allowed to go below the screen
    if (right_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT > SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        right_paddle_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT;


    // Left paddle shouldn't be allowed to go above the screen
    if (left_paddle_y < 0)
        left_paddle_y = 0;

    // Left paddle shouldn't be allowed to below the screen
    else if (left_paddle_y + PADDLE_HEIGHT > SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        left_paddle_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - PADDLE_HEIGHT;

    // We're done updating values if the ball hasn't been launched yet
    if (!launch_ball)
        return;

    // Three hits => increment ball speed and reset hit counter
    if (hit_count == 3) {
        speed++;
        hit_count = 0;
    }

    // Smooth collision between ball and left paddle
    if (checkLeftCollision()) {
            if (bounce) {
                // y coordinate of the ball in relation to the left paddle (from 0 to 70)
                int left_relative_y = (y_ball - left_paddle_y + BALL_HEIGHT);

                // Angle formed between ball direction and left paddle after collision
                angle = (2.14f * left_relative_y - 75.0f);

                ball_dx = speed*cos(angle*M_PI/180.0f); // convert angle to radian, find its cos() and multiply by the speed
                ball_dy = speed*sin(angle*M_PI/180.0f); // convert angle to radina, find its sin() and multiply by the speed
                bounce = false;                         // finished bouncing

            }
            x_ball = left_paddle_x + PADDLE_WIDTH;      // deposit ball on left paddle surface (smooth collision)
            bounce = true;                              // bounce ball on next frame
            Mix_PlayChannel(-1, paddle_sound, 0);       // Play collision sound
    }

    // Smooth collision between ball and right paddle
    else if (checkRightCollision()) {
            if (bounce) {
                // y coordinate of the ball in relation to the right paddle (from 0 to 70)
                int right_relative_y = (y_ball - right_paddle_y + BALL_HEIGHT);

                // Angle formed between ball direction and right paddle after collision
                angle = (2.14 * right_relative_y - 75.0f);

                ball_dx = -speed*cos(angle*M_PI/180.0f);// convert angle to radian, find its cos() and multiply by the negative of speed
                ball_dy = speed*sin(angle*M_PI/180.0f); // convert angle to radian, find its sin() and multiply by the speed
                bounce = false;                         // finished bouncing
            }
            x_ball = right_paddle_x - BALL_WIDTH;       // deposit ball on surface right paddle surface (smooth collision)
            hit_count++;                                // increment hit counter
            bounce = true;                              // bounce ball on next frame
            Mix_PlayChannel(-1, paddle_sound, 0);       // play collision sound

            final_predicted_y = predict();              // predict ball position for AI to intercept

    }

    // Upper and bottom walls collision
    else if ( (y_ball + ball_dy < 0) || (y_ball + BALL_HEIGHT + ball_dy >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) ) {
        ball_dy *= -1;                                  // reverse ball direction on y-axis
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, wall_sound, 0);             // play collision sound
    }

    // No collision occurs, update ball coordinates
    else {
        x_ball += ball_dx;
        y_ball += ball_dy;
    }

    // If ball goes out...
    if (x_ball > SCREEN_WIDTH || x_ball < 0) {

        // Change score
        if (x_ball > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            score1++;
            left_score_changed = true;
        } else {
            score2++;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }

        // Play score sound
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, score_sound, 0); 

        // Reset ball position as before launch
        x_ball = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
        y_ball = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

        // Ball is fixed
        ball_dx = 0;
        ball_dy = 0;
        launch_ball = false;

        // Speed and hit counter are reset to their initial positions
        speed = 8;
        hit_count = 0; 
    }

}

// Render objects on screen
void render() {

    // Clear screen (background color)
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 67, 68, 69, 255 );        // dark grey
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // Color left background with light grey
    SDL_Rect left_background = { SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 187, 191, 194, 255 );
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &left_background );

    // Paddle color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 212, 120, 102, 255 );

    // Render filled paddle
    SDL_Rect paddle1 = { left_paddle_x, left_paddle_y, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT };
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &paddle1 );

    // Render filled paddle
    SDL_Rect paddle2 = { right_paddle_x, right_paddle_y, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT };
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &paddle2 );

    // Render ball
    SDL_Rect ball = { x_ball - BALL_WIDTH / 2, y_ball, BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT };
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &ball);

    // Render scores
    if (left_score_changed) {
        font_image_score1 = renderText(to_string(score1), "Lato-Reg.TTF", light_font, 24, renderer);
        left_score_changed = false;
    }
    renderTexture(font_image_score1, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 4 / 10, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 12);

    int score_font_size = 24;
    if (right_score_changed) {
        font_image_score2 = renderText(to_string(score2), "Lato-Reg.TTF", dark_font, score_font_size, renderer);
        right_score_changed = false;

    }
    renderTexture(font_image_score2, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/ 12);

    // Render text indicating the winner
    if (score1 == 5) {
        font_image_winner = renderText("Player 1 won!", fonts[0], light_font, 24, renderer);
        renderTexture(font_image_winner, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1 / 10 + 3, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4);   // align with score
        font_image_restart = renderText("Press SPACE to restart", fonts[0], light_font, 18, renderer);
        renderTexture(font_image_restart, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1 / 10 + 3, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3);
        if (launch_ball) {
            score1 = 0;
            score2 = 0;
            left_score_changed = true;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }
    } else if (score2 == 5) {
        font_image_winner = renderText("Player 2 won!", fonts[0], dark_font, 24, renderer);
        renderTexture(font_image_winner, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4);   // align with score
        font_image_restart = renderText("Press SPACE to restart", fonts[0], dark_font, 18, renderer);
        renderTexture(font_image_restart, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3);
        if (launch_ball) {
            score1 = 0;
            score2 = 0;
            left_score_changed = true;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }
    }

    // Draw "Press SPACE to start"
    else if (!launch_ball) {
        renderTexture(font_image_launch1, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 80, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25);
        renderTexture(font_image_launch2, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 1, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25);
    }

    // Swap buffers
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

}

void cleanUp() {

    // Destroy textures
    SDL_DestroyTexture(font_image_score1);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(font_image_score2);

    // Free the sound effects
    Mix_FreeChunk(paddle_sound);
    Mix_FreeChunk(wall_sound);
    Mix_FreeChunk(score_sound);

    // Quit SDL_mixer
    Mix_CloseAudio();

    // Destroy renderer and window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Shuts down SDL
    SDL_Quit();
}

void gameLoop() {

    while(!done) {
        input();
        update();
        render();
    }

    cleanUp();
}

void initialize() {

    // Initialize SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Create window in the middle of the screen
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Pong",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // Create renderer in order to draw on window
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

    // Initialize font
    TTF_Init();

    // Holds text "Press SPACE to start"
    font_image_launch1 = renderText("Press SPA", fonts[0], light_font, 18, renderer);
    font_image_launch2 = renderText("CE to start", fonts[0], dark_font, 18, renderer);

    // Initialize SDL_Mixer
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024);

    // Load sounds
    paddle_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("./sounds/paddle_hit.wav");
    wall_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("./sounds/wall_hit.wav");
    score_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("./sounds/score_update.wav");

    // Don't show cursor
    SDL_ShowCursor(0);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    initialize();
    gameLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Global variables**

You have *many* global variables, which is very bad.  In general, global variables should be avoided as they can be modified anywhere in the program and at any time.  This especially makes debugging difficult as you won't be able to keep track of where these variables could have been modified, as it can happen anywhere in the program.

I also cannot tell which of these should be constants (minus the two that are already constants).  If any of them should be a constant, add `const`.  Those can then stay there as they'll no longer be mutable.

For the rest, you should be passing them to functions as needed, or just keep them in one function if they're only used in one.  They can be passed separately, or encapsulated in a container class, depending on the situation.  This will give you a much better idea of how each variable is used, making debugging and maintainability easier.

**Classes**

Yes, you should consider using OOP or at least just classes.  I'm not too familiar with OOP, so I won't go more into that.  But I can say that you should at least consider having a `Game` class and probably additional classes if needed.

With this, yes, you'll need to have multiple files.  The driver file will just have `main()` and will include any needed headers.  A separate header and implementation file will be for `Game`.  In the driver, you create a `Game` object, which will essentially run the game.

You could also have, say, a `Ball` class and a `Paddle` class.  Basically, if you have some "object" that holds data and has functions to modify that data, it could have its own class.  This will help encapsulate your program even more, allowing you to manage these separate classes instead of just straight functions and variables that can correspond with anything.

**Misc.**

- [I'd recommend against using `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- I see that you use `nullptr`, yet your `std::srand()` call uses `NULL`.  If you have access to `nullptr`, you should use it everywhere as needed and replace `NULL`.
- As you are using C++11, you should no longer use `std::srand()` and `std::rand()`.  You should instead consider any of the new functionality found in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random).

Answer (score 12):

> Would it be better to use OOP?

I'd prefer it if you did: I find it easier to read.

Your variables are already well-commented and grouped into ... groups.

```
// Screen resolution
// Controllers
// Mouse coordinates;
// Paddle lengths
// Paddle position
// Launch ball
// Ball dimensions
// Ball position
// Ball movement
// Match score
// Prediction
// Font names
```

To start with you can refactor that into structs:

```
// Ball position
int x_ball = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
int y_ball = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

// Ball movement
int ball_dx = 0;        // movement in pixels (speed) over the x-axis
int ball_dy = 0;        // movement in pixels (speed) over the y-axis

int speed = 8;          // ball speed = √(dx²+dy²)
```

... becomes ...

```
struct Ball
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int speed;
};
```

That alone is a win:

- Assuming there's an instance of `Ball` named `ball`, and assuming you name the parameter `ball` whenever you pass it by parameter, I can search the code for 'ball' to see all lines of code which affect the ball
- You can more easily change the game to contain more than one ball instance
- You can refactor some details, for example make speed a method instead of an independent variable:

  ```
  int speed() const { return (int)sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); }
  ```
- If you make the data private and accessed via accessor method like `void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }` and `int getX() const { return x; }` then I can find the places where `x` is being written and where it's being read
- You can move more functionality into the class; for example you don't change `x` and `y` independently, you change them both at the same time, so there should probably be one `Ball` method which changes both of them
- After you've moved most of the functionality into helper methods of the various classes, then the remaining logic of the game is clearer: the game code will say what happens in each turn but doesn't need to say how (the 'how' is implemented inside helper methods like `bool ball.CollidesWith(const Paddle&) const { ... }`).

This looks like good C code. It isn't really "C++" code (no classes, not OOP).

On a minor note I'm not sure that your checkColission functions are completely accurate: for example because they're ignoring ball_dy. You need a little trignometry there: add a little bit of dy, depending on what percentage of dx is required to reach the paddle line.

Comment: *It isn't really "C++" code (no classes, not OOP)* Classes and OOP are not what makes code "C++". What makes (this) code "C" is reliance on legacy C mechanisms (manual resource lifetime management) where C++ offers less error-prone solutions (RAII in general, `std::unique_ptr` in particular)

Comment: The code in the OP literally looks like C (not C++) code, which would compile with a C compiler.

Comment: Anyway, the code works and right API functions are called in the right order. It would need the restructuring you suggest, whether "C" or "C++". I mean that to deem it "C++", I would not require usage of classes and OOP as you mention, but of RAII, `<math>` and `<random>` instead of resp. manual resource management, `<cmath>` and `<ctime>`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my two cents:

- The call to `cleanUp` is misplaced with regards to `initialize`, since the former undoes what the latter does. It should be taken out of `gameLoop` and called right after it.

In C++, there is something called RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). A resource is something external to your program, that your program has to borrow AND give back. (file handles `fopen`/`fclose`, chunks of heap memory `malloc`/`free`, free-store objects `new`/`delete`, textures `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`/`SDL_DestroyTexture`, ...)

Since you're using `nullptr`, I bet you are using C++11. C++11 provides smart pointers to automatically manage resources. Since you're owning resources like textures, surfaces and the like, here is an example to use `unique_ptr`to manage your resources.

```
#include <memory>

namespace internal {
    struct TextureDeleter {
        void operator()(SDL_Texture* resource) {
            if(resource != nullptr) {
                SDL_DestroyTexture(resource);
            }
        }
    }
}

using Texture = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, internal::TextureDeleter>;
```

Now, you have a type name `Texture` which represents a smart pointer on `SDL_Texture`. When an object of this type is destroyed, `SDL_DestroyTexture` will be called on the owned `SDL_Texture*`.

Use this type for textures you have to free at some point. (`font_image_score1`,...) The lifetime of your `SDL_Texture` will then match the lifetime of your objects, which is why they have to be as local as possible. (instead of global variables, as suggested by another answer) In particular, their lifetime have to be strictly contained between `SDL_Init` and `SDL_Quit`.

Make your resources more local, and use RAII, and you'll see your resource-freeing code disintegrate like a start-up.

There are other idioms usable for system initialization (involving `weak_ptr`s) but that's a bit out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty code, for your first game. I like that you commented each variable at the top.

I would recommend against using OOP or multiple files. It takes time away from what should be a fluid iterative process of tweaking the game as you play it.

In fact, for something this simple, I wouldn't even use C++, C would have worked just as well.

But, more importantly, that's not how Pong works! The paddle is divided into a small amount of regions, each of which reflects the ball in a different way. See Diagram \$6(b)\$ [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2007/LABS/LAB4/lab4.pdf) for more information.