# Pong game written in C++ and using SDL 2.0 (part 2)

Tags: c++, game, c++11, sdl

I have previously asked [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42823/pong-game-written-in-c-and-using-sdl-2-0) for a review of my Pong game. Since then I have implemented most of the recommendations but I'm not sure I did so correctly, the result can be found on my [github](https://github.com/chaficnajjar/pong).

Would it be possible to get another review? Below is the whole source code of the game:

**main.cpp**

```
/*
 *  Pong game
 *  Author: Chafic Najjar <chafic.najjar@gmail.com>
 *  Note: Origin of the coordinate system is the upper left corner of the screen
 */

#include "pong.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Pong pong(argc, argv);
    pong.execute();

    return 0;

}
```

**pong.hpp**

```
/*
 *  Pong class declaration
 */

#ifndef PONG_HPP
#define PONG_HPP

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>                       // SDL library
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>                   // SDL font library
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>                 // SDL sound library

#include <iostream>

class Ball;
class Paddle;

class Pong {

public:
    Pong(int argc, char *argv[]);

    /* Screen resolution */
    static const int SCREEN_WIDTH;
    static const int SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    /* Window and renderer */
    SDL_Window* window;                     // holds window properties
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;                 // holds rendering surface properties

    /* Game objects */
    Ball *ball;
    Paddle *left_paddle;
    Paddle *right_paddle;

    /* Sounds */
    Mix_Chunk *paddle_sound;                // holds sound produced after ball collides with paddle
    Mix_Chunk *wall_sound;                  // holds sound produced after ball collides with wall
    Mix_Chunk *score_sound;                 // holds sound produced when updating score

    /* Controllers */
    enum Controllers { mouse, keyboard, joystick };
    Controllers controller;
    SDL_Joystick *gamepad;                  // holds joystick information
    int gamepad_direction;                  // gamepad direction
    int mouse_x, mouse_y;                   // mouse coordinates

    /* Fonts */
    std::string fonts[2];                   // font names
    SDL_Color dark_font;                    // dark font color
    SDL_Color light_font;                   // light font color
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_left_score;  // holds text indicating player 1 score (left)
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_right_score; // holds text indicating palyer 2 score (right)
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_winner;      // holds text indicating winner
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_restart;     // holds text suggesting to restart the game
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_launch1;     // holds first part of text suggesting to launch the ball
    SDL_Texture*    font_image_launch2;     // holds second part of text suggesting to launch the ball

    /* Scores */
    int left_score;     
    int right_score;
    bool left_score_changed;                // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 
    bool right_score_changed;               // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 

    /* Game states */
    bool exit;                              // true when player wants to exit game

    /* Main functions */
    void execute();

    void input();
    void update();
    void render();

    void clean_up();

};

#endif
```

**pong.cpp**

```
/*
 *  Pong class definition
 */

#include "pong.hpp"
#include "ball.hpp"
#include "paddle.hpp"
#include "utilities.hpp"

/* Screen resolution */
const int Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

Pong::Pong(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* Initilize SDL */
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_ShowCursor(0);      // don't show cursor

    /* Window and renderer */
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,        // centered window
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,        // centered window
            SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

    /* Game objects */
    ball = new Ball(SCREEN_WIDTH/2-ball->LENGTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
    left_paddle = new Paddle(40, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-30);
    right_paddle = new Paddle(SCREEN_WIDTH-(40+Paddle::WIDTH), SCREEN_HEIGHT/2-30);

    /* Sounds */
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024);  // initialize SDL_mixer

    paddle_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("resources/sounds/paddle_hit.wav");      // load paddle sound
    wall_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("resources/sounds/wall_hit.wav");          // load wall sound
    score_sound = Mix_LoadWAV("resources/sounds/score_update.wav");     // load score sound

    /* Controllers */
    if (argc == 2) { 
        if ( strcmp(argv[1], "keyboard") == 0 )
            controller = keyboard;
        else if ( strcmp(argv[1], "joystick") == 0 )
            controller = joystick;
        else
            controller = mouse;
    } else
        controller = mouse;     // default controller

    if (controller == joystick) {
        printf("%i joysticks were found.\n\n", SDL_NumJoysticks() );
        printf("The names of the joysticks are:\n");

        gamepad = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);          // give control to the first joystick
        for(int i = 0; i < SDL_NumJoysticks(); i++) 
            std::cout << "\t" << SDL_JoystickName(gamepad) << std::endl;

        SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);     // initialize joystick controller

        gamepad_direction = 0;
    }

    /* Fonts */
    TTF_Init();     // initialize font

    dark_font = {67, 68, 69};       // dark grey
    light_font = {187, 191, 194};   // light grey

    fonts[0] = "resources/fonts/Lato-Reg.TTF";
    fonts[1] = "resources/fonts/FFFFORWA.TTF";

    font_image_launch1 = renderText("Press SPA", fonts[0], light_font, 18, renderer);
    font_image_launch2 = renderText("CE to start", fonts[0], dark_font, 18, renderer);

    /* Scores */
    left_score = 0;
    right_score = 0;
    left_score_changed = true;     // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 
    right_score_changed = true;    // indicates when rendering new score is necessary 

    /* Game states */
    exit = false;

}

void Pong::execute() {

    while(!exit) {
        input();
        update();
        render();
    }

    clean_up();
}

void Pong::input() {

    //=== Handling events ===//

    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        // Track mouse movement
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);

        // Clicking 'x' or pressing F4
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            exit = true;

        // Joystick direction controller moved
        if (event.type == SDL_JOYAXISMOTION) {
            // 32767
            // Up or down
            if (event.jaxis.axis == 1)
                gamepad_direction = event.jaxis.value/5461;
        }

        // Joystick action button pressed
        if (event.type == SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN) 
            if (ball->status == ball->READY)
                ball->status = ball->LAUNCH;

        // Pressing a key
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {

                // Pressing ESC exits from the game
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    exit = true;
                    break;

                // Pressing space will launch the ball if it isn't already launched
                case SDLK_SPACE:
                    if (ball->status == ball->READY)
                        ball->status = ball->LAUNCH;
                    break;


                // Pressing F11 to toggle fullscreen
                case SDLK_F11:
                    int flags = SDL_GetWindowFlags(window);
                    if(flags & SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
                        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, 0);
                    else
                        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
                    break;
            }
    }
}

// Update game values
void Pong::update() {

    //=======================//
    //=== Paddle movement ===//

    // Right paddle follows the player's mouse on the y-axis
    if (controller == mouse)
        right_paddle->set_y(mouse_y);

    // Right paddle follows the player's gamepad
    else if (controller == joystick)
        right_paddle->add_to_y(gamepad_direction);

    // AI paddle movement
    left_paddle->AI(ball);


    //===================//
    //=== Launch ball ===//

    if (ball->status == ball->READY)
        return;

    else if (ball->status == ball->LAUNCH) {
        ball->launch_ball(left_paddle);
        ball->predicted_y = left_paddle->predict(ball);
    }


    //=========================//
    //=== Update ball speed ===//

    ball->update_speed();


    //=================//
    //=== Collision ===//

    if (ball->collides_with(left_paddle)) {
        ball->bounces_off(left_paddle);
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, paddle_sound, 0);           // play collision sound
    }

    else if (ball->collides_with(right_paddle)) {
        ball->bounces_off(right_paddle);
        ball->predicted_y = left_paddle->predict(ball); // predict ball position on the y-axis
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, paddle_sound, 0);
    }

    // Upper and bottom walls collision
    if (ball->wall_collision()) {
        ball->dy *= -1;                                 // reverse ball direction on y-axis
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, wall_sound, 0);             // play collision sound
    }


    //===============================//
    //=== Update ball coordinates ===//

    ball->x += ball->dx;
    ball->y += ball->dy;


    //=====================//
    //=== Ball goes out ===//

    if (ball->x > SCREEN_WIDTH || ball->x < 0) {

        // Change score
        if (ball->x > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
            left_score++;
            left_score_changed = true;
        } else {
            right_score++;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }

        Mix_PlayChannel(-1, score_sound, 0); 

        ball->reset();
    }

}

// Render objects on screen
void Pong::render() {

    // Clear screen (background color)
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 67, 68, 69, 255 );        // dark grey
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    // Color left background with light grey
    SDL_Rect left_background = { SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 187, 191, 194, 255 );
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &left_background );

    // Paddle color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 212, 120, 102, 255 );

    // Render filled paddle
    SDL_Rect paddle1 = { left_paddle->get_x(), left_paddle->get_y(), Paddle::WIDTH, Paddle::HEIGHT };
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &paddle1 );

    // Render filled paddle
    SDL_Rect paddle2 = { right_paddle->get_x(), right_paddle->get_y(), Paddle::WIDTH, Paddle::HEIGHT };
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &paddle2 );

    // Render ball
    SDL_Rect pong_ball = { ball->x, ball->y, ball->LENGTH, ball->LENGTH };
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &pong_ball);

    // Render scores
    if (left_score_changed) {
        font_image_left_score = renderText(std::to_string(left_score), "resources/fonts/Lato-Reg.TTF", light_font, 24, renderer);
        left_score_changed = false;
        if (left_score == 5) {
            font_image_winner = renderText("Player 1 won!", fonts[0], light_font, 24, renderer);
            font_image_restart = renderText("Press SPACE to restart", fonts[0], light_font, 18, renderer);
        }
    }
    renderTexture(font_image_left_score, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 4 / 10, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 12);

    int score_font_size = 24;
    if (right_score_changed) {
        font_image_right_score = renderText(std::to_string(right_score), "resources/fonts/Lato-Reg.TTF", dark_font, score_font_size, renderer);
        right_score_changed = false;
        if (right_score == 5) {
            font_image_winner = renderText("Player 2 won!", fonts[0], dark_font, 24, renderer);
            font_image_restart = renderText("Press SPACE to restart", fonts[0], dark_font, 18, renderer);
        }

    }
    renderTexture(font_image_right_score, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/ 12);

    // Render text indicating the winner
    if (left_score == 5) {
        renderTexture(font_image_winner, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1 / 10 + 3, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4);   // align with score
        renderTexture(font_image_restart, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 1 / 10 + 3, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3);
        if (ball->status == ball->LAUNCHED) {
            left_score = 0;
            right_score = 0;
            left_score_changed = true;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }
    } else if (right_score == 5) {
        renderTexture(font_image_winner, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4);   // align with score
        renderTexture(font_image_restart, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH * 6 / 10 - score_font_size/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3);
        if (ball->status == ball->LAUNCHED) {
            left_score = 0;
            right_score = 0;
            left_score_changed = true;
            right_score_changed = true;
        }
    }

    // Draw "Press SPACE to start"
    else if (!ball->status == ball->LAUNCHED) {
        renderTexture(font_image_launch1, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 80, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25);
        renderTexture(font_image_launch2, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 1, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 25);
    }

    // Swap buffers
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

}

//=== Release resources ===//
void Pong::clean_up() {

    // Destroy textures
    SDL_DestroyTexture(font_image_left_score);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(font_image_right_score);

    // Free the sound effects
    Mix_FreeChunk(paddle_sound);
    Mix_FreeChunk(wall_sound);
    Mix_FreeChunk(score_sound);

    // Quit SDL_mixer
    Mix_CloseAudio();

    // Close joystick
    if (controller == joystick)
        SDL_JoystickClose(gamepad);

    // Destroy renderer and window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Shuts down SDL
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**paddle.hpp**

```
/*
 *  Paddle class declaration
 */

#ifndef PADDLE_HPP
#define PADDLE_HPP

class Ball;

class Paddle {
private:
    // Paddle position
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Paddle(int x, int y);

public:
    // Paddle dimensions
    static const int HEIGHT;
    static const int WIDTH;

    // Functions
    int get_x();
    int get_y();
    void set_y(int new_y);
    void add_to_y(int new_y);
    int predict(Ball *ball);
    void AI(Ball *ball);
};

#endif
```

**paddle.cpp**

```
/*
 *  Paddle class definitions
 */

#include "paddle.hpp"
#include "pong.hpp"
#include "ball.hpp"

const int Paddle::HEIGHT = 60;
const int Paddle::WIDTH = 10;

Paddle::Paddle(int new_x, int new_y){
    x = new_x;
    y = new_y;
}

int Paddle::get_x() {
    return x;
}

int Paddle::get_y() {
    return y;
}

void Paddle::set_y(int new_y) {
    y = new_y;

    // Paddle shouldn't be allowed to go above or below the screen
    if (y < 0)
        y = 0;
    else if (y + HEIGHT > Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        y = Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT - HEIGHT;
}

void Paddle::add_to_y(int new_y) {
    y += new_y;

    // Paddle shouldn't be allowed to go above or below the screen
    if (y < 0)
        y = 0;
    else if (y + HEIGHT > Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        y = Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT - HEIGHT; 
}

// Imprecise prediction of ball position on the y-axis
int Paddle::predict(Ball *ball) {

    // Find slope
    float slope = (float)(ball->y - ball->y+ball->dy)/(ball->x - ball->x+ball->dx);

    // Distance between ball and paddle
    int paddle_distance = ball->x - x;

    // Prediction without taking into consideration upper and bottom wall collisions
    int predicted_y = abs(slope * -(paddle_distance) + ball->y);

    // Calculate number of reflexions
    int number_of_reflexions = predicted_y / Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    // Predictions taking into consideration upper and bottom wall collisions
    if (number_of_reflexions % 2 == 0)                      // Even number of reflexions
        predicted_y = predicted_y % Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    else                                                    // Odd number of reflexsion
        predicted_y = Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT - (predicted_y % Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    return predicted_y; 
}

// Basic AI movement
void Paddle::AI(Ball *ball) {

    // Ball on the left 3/5th side of the screen and going left
    if (ball->x < Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH*3/5 && ball->dx < 0) {
        // Follow the ball
        if (y + (HEIGHT - ball->LENGTH)/2 < ball->predicted_y-2)
            add_to_y(ball->speed/8 * 5);
        else if (y + (HEIGHT - ball->LENGTH)/2 > ball->predicted_y+2)
            add_to_y( -(ball->speed/8 * 5) );
    }

    // Ball is anywhere on the screen but going right
    else if (ball->dx >= 0) {
        // Left paddle slowly moves to the center
        if (y + HEIGHT / 2 < Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)
            add_to_y(2);
        else if (y + HEIGHT / 2 > Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT/2) 
            add_to_y(-2);
    }

}
```

**ball.hpp**

```
/*
 *  Ball class declaration
 */

#ifndef BALL_HPP
#define BALL_HPP

class Paddle;

class Ball {
    public:
        Ball(int x, int y);

        // Ball status
        enum Status {READY, LAUNCH, LAUNCHED};
        Status status;

        // Ball dimensions
        static const int LENGTH;

        // Ball position
        int x;
        int y;

        // Ball movement
        int dx;             // movement in pixels over the x-axis for the next frame (speed on the x-axis)
        int dy;             // movement in pixels over the y-axis for the next frame (speed on the y-axis)

        bool bounce;        // true when next frame renders ball after collision impact (ball has bounced)
        int speed;          // ball speed = √(dx²+dy²)
        float angle;        // angle after collision with paddle
        int hits;           // counts the number of hits of the ball with the right paddle, increase speed after 3 hits
        int predicted_y;    // predicted ball position on y-axis after right paddle collision (used for paddle AI)

        void launch_ball(Paddle *ai_paddle);
        void update_speed();
        bool wall_collision();
        bool collides_with(Paddle *paddle);
        void bounces_off(Paddle *paddle);
        void reset();
};

#endif
```

**ball.cpp**

```
/*
 *  Ball class definitions
 */

#include "ball.hpp"
#include "pong.hpp"
#include "paddle.hpp"
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

// Ball dimensions
const int Ball::LENGTH = 10;

Ball::Ball(int x, int y) {

    // Ball status
    status = READY;

    // Ball position
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;

    // Ball movement
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    bounce = false;
    speed = 8;
    angle = 0.0f;
    hits = 0;      
    predicted_y = 0;
}

void Ball::launch_ball(Paddle *ai_paddle) {

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dir(0, 1);
    int direction = 1+(-2)*(dir(gen)%2);                        // either 1 or -1

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ang(-60, 60);
    angle = ang(gen);                                           // between -60 and 60

    dx = direction*speed*cos(angle*M_PI/180.0f);                // speed on the x-axis
    dy = speed*sin(angle*M_PI/180.0f);                          // speed on the y-axis

    status = LAUNCHED;
}

void Ball::bounces_off(Paddle *paddle) {

    if (paddle == nullptr)
        return;

        hits++; 

        int sign;
        if (paddle->get_x() < Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH/2)
            sign = 1;
        else
            sign = -1;

        int relative_y = (y - paddle->get_y() + LENGTH);

        angle = (2.14f * relative_y - 75.0f);

        dx = sign*speed*cos(angle*M_PI/180.0f);     // convert angle to radian, find its cos() and multiply by the speed
        dy = speed*sin(angle*M_PI/180.0f);          // convert angle to radina, find its sin() and multiply by the speed

}

void Ball::update_speed() {
    // Increment ball speed for every 6 hits 
    if (hits == 5) {
        speed++;
        hits = 0;
    }
}

bool Ball::wall_collision() {
    return (y + dy < 0) || (y + LENGTH + dy >= Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}

bool Ball::collides_with(Paddle *paddle) {

    // left paddle
    if (paddle->get_x() < Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH/2) {
        // Check if collision with left paddle occurs in next frame
        if ( x > paddle->get_x() + Paddle::WIDTH )
            return false;
        else if (x < paddle->get_x())
            return false;
        else if (!(y + LENGTH > paddle->get_y() && y <= paddle->get_y() + Paddle::HEIGHT))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // right paddle
    else {
        // Check if collision with right paddle occurs in next frame
        if ( x + LENGTH < paddle->get_x() )
            return false;
        else if (x > paddle->get_x() + Paddle::WIDTH)
            return false;
        else if (!(y + LENGTH > paddle->get_y() && y <= paddle->get_y() + Paddle::HEIGHT))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}

// Reset ball to initial state
void Ball::reset() {
    x = Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - LENGTH/2;
    y = Pong::SCREEN_HEIGHT/2;

    // Ball is fixed
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    status = READY;

    // Speed and hit counter are reset to their initial positions
    speed = 8;
    hits = 0;
}
```

**utilities.hpp**

```
/* 
 *  Useful functions
 */

#ifndef UTILITIES_HPP
#define UTILITIES_HPP

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, SDL_Rect dst, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, clip, &dst);
}

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, int x, int y, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr) {
    SDL_Rect dst;
    dst.x = x;
    dst.y = y;
    if (clip != nullptr){
        dst.w = clip->w;
        dst.h = clip->h;
    }

    else
        SDL_QueryTexture(tex, nullptr, nullptr, &dst.w, &dst.h);

    renderTexture(tex, ren, dst, clip);
}

SDL_Texture* renderText(const std::string &message, const std::string &fontFile, SDL_Color color, int fontSize, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);

    SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);

    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    return texture;
}

#endif
```

Comment: When running I show: error: 'abs' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You don't need `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  Reaching that point already implies a successful termination, so the compiler will insert it for you.
- Prefer to avoid raw pointers and manual memory management whenever possible.  Instead, utilize standard containers and C++11 smart pointers.

  With raw pointers as data members, you would have to maintain [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (or [The Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) in C++11) because the provided copy constructor and assignment operator will only copy the pointers (shallow copy), not the data they point to (deep copy).
- Utilize initializer lists for your classes:

  `Ball`:

  ```
  Ball::Ball(int x, int y)
      : status(READY)
      , x(x)
      , y(y)
      , bounce(false);
      , speed(8);
      , angle(0.0f);
      , hits(0);      
      , predicted_y(0)
  {}
  ```

  `Paddle`:

  ```
  Paddle::Paddle(int new_x, int new_y)
      : x(new_x)
      , y(new_y)
  {}
  ```

  This will especially be helpful in case you ever need to initialize `const` members.
- `Paddle`'s accessors should be `const` as they do not modify data members:

  ```
  int Paddle::get_x() const {
      return x;
  }
  ```

  ```
  int Paddle::get_y() const {
      return y;
  }
  ```
- Your randomization initializations should be put into an anonymous namespace:

  ```
  namespace {
      std::random_device rd;
      std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  }
  ```

  This will prevent linker errors in case the same names are used in other files.
- This:

  ```
  int sign;
  if (paddle->get_x() < Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH/2)
      sign = 1;
  else
      sign = -1;
  ```

  can become a single-line ternary statement:

  ```
  int sign = (paddle->get_x() < Pong::SCREEN_WIDTH/2) ? 1 : -1;
  ```
- You're using `sin()` and `cos()`, but you haven't included `<cmath>`.  I assume your compiler is being lenient for some reason and is not raising errors.  You should still include this, as well as prefixing the functions with `std::`.
- In `collides_with()`, I'd condense all the `if`/`else if` statements into one `if`, with each condition separated by a `||`.  Only one of them has to be met to `return false`.

  You'll then have something in this form (separate `||` lines may be necessary):

  ```
  if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3)
      return false;
  else
      return true;
  ```

Comment: “_Your randomization initializations should be put into an anonymous namespace_” — why is that?

Comment: @You: It was based on advice given to me [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/31714/22222).  I just haven't provided those details in this answer.  I'll do that soon.

Answer (score 3):

I just have a few additional comments.

First: (My main one) please, for the sake of all the furry little animals, your mother, and anything that's lovable in the world, don't hard-code the screen-width and screen-height as 640x480. Write your code to detect the screen size at run-time and act accordingly.

Second, I'd wrap the `M_PI/180.0f` in a constant, by strong preference inside a function:

```
template <class T>
deg2rad(double degrees) { 
     T factor = static_cast<T>(M_PI/180.0);
     return degrees * factor;
}
```

My other main suggestion would be to move more of the intelligence about the game out of `pong::update` and into the individual objects. For example, right now the code for handling a collision between the ball and a wall or paddle isn't handled by the ball or the wall or the paddle. IMO, it would be better if the ball and/or object it collided with handled the collision, rather than leaving it to "outside" code (though I'll openly admit that collisions between different types of objects is a problem can be difficult to keep completely object oriented).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your first point, can you give an example?